# Variable 'this' undefined in Chrome Debugger but logged on console and defined in Scope.Local (In async method)

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, my Chrome Debugger is killing me.
Firstly, it started with not showing the current source code but some previous state. I could fix that by closing and reopening the devtools. I also deleted the dist folder and rebuilt the project.

But now it makes debugging annoying by showing wrong values of the variables.
However, in the Scope.Local and in the console the value is visible but not in the watch or when hovering on it.

Does anybody know how to get it running again?

EDIT:

The called method was prefixed with 'async'. If I removed that, I was able to see again the value in the debugger. But I still would like to keep it with the async prefix

Comment: I found some more info here

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143598
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31730

Comment: Just do a console.log of whatever value you want to see, async await has always been a problem in chrome debugger!